# How can I renew an expiring but still valid intermediate CA using openssl?

Tags: openvpn, openssl

We have our own CA infrastructure for an OpenVPN server. We created a self signed root CA, and then one intermediate CA for each OpenVPN process / network. We created the intermediate CA with the following commands:

```
openssl req -new -batch -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes sha256 -keyout network.hostname.ca.key -out sign_request.csr -subj "/C=land/ST=region/L=town/O=org/OU=CAnetwork/CN=cn/emailAddress=email" -config /path/to/config
openssl ca -cert root.ca.crt -keyfile root.ca.key -in sign_request.csr -out network.hostname.ca.crt -noemailDN -md sha256 -extensions v3_ca -outdir /some/dir -config /path/to/config -batch
```

Now, our intermediate CA is about to expire (in a few months) and I want to renew the certificate. I tried doing that by running exactly the same command as 10 years ago with the exception that I am using the old key of the intermediate ca instead of generating a new one (since I want the issued certificates to stay valid!). However, this complains that `Serial number 01 has already been issued`. Serial 01 is the serial number of the current/expiring intermediate ca.

How can I get openssl to ignore the existing valid intermediate CA and recreate it with a longer validity so that the new CA will still verify client certificates created with the old expiring CA?

Comment: You cant. New ca means new keys and means yuo should gen new server cert signed with new interm ca

Comment: Since I control all the keys and everything myself, I don't necessarily need new keys. Maybe I did not express myself clearly: I want to renew my CA's certificate so that it's valid for another 10 years.

Comment: You simply dont understand how it works

Comment: Renew - means create totaly new certificate. You cant "edit" certificate to change somthing in it. You can only generate new cert with new expire date. You cant generate the same cert with new expire date. So you should generate all new client certs signed by new CA cert. Thats whole point if cert expiration - you cant use it after. And all certs signed with it become invalid

Comment: I don't think you are entirely correct. I have actually managed to create a new cert with the old private key which validates certificates issued by the old ca with the old cert. This article also states that renewal with old keys is possible: https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/ejbca-operations/ejbca-operations-guide/ca-operations-guide/end-entities/certificate-renewal

Comment: Edit or recreate CA database files to wipe out info about issued certs

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your CSR generation command is wrong:

```bash
openssl req -new -batch -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes sha256 -keyout network.hostname.ca.key -out sign_request.csr -subj "/C=land/ST=region/L=town/O=org/OU=CAnetwork/CN=cn/emailAddress=email" -config /path/to/config
```

Will create a completely new key named network.hostname.ca.key.  If you want to truly renew you probably want to use the existing key. Which I think would look something like this:

```bash
openssl req -new -batch -days 3650 -key network.hostname.ca.key -sha256 -out sign_request.csr -subj "/C=land/ST=region/L=town/O=org/OU=CAnetwork/CN=cn/emailAddress=email" -config /path/to/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you can't have 2 certs with the same CN valid at the same time. There is an option in openssl.cnf to allow that but that's not what you want. Think it's better to revoke the int ca and the create a new request using the same private key and same attributes and get that signed. Should meet all your needs

Found this link explains it well

https://serverfault.com/questions/306345/certification-authority-root-certificate-expiry-and-renewal

EDIT:
add more to this. seems like certificate validation includes not only that the
issuer == int ca subject
issuer serial # == int ca serial number

so just renewing the int ca with the same details - you get a different serial number